# Creating Product Table using Gutenberg

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to display products in table form so, customers can buy products in bulk. So can I create a product table using Gutenberg editor or need to add product table plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after wandering around the Google and playing with Gutenberg I was able to create a table like this 
[image]

But, it was basic one and missing add to cart button and other eCommerce functionalities. So I looked for the product table plugin and found the barn2 product table that delivers all the features that I was looking for.
And I also found another product table plugin on WooCommerce which offers the same functionality and to my surprise! It's cheaper than barn2 and costs only $49.

its probably new so, a lot of people might not have heard about this product table plugin and here is link 
https://woocommerce.com/products/product-tables-for-woocommerce/

So, after testing it for a while, I will share my review